How to save charts and corresponding data after running the model
I have created several charts in my model. After running the model, I want to save those chart as image and want to get the corresponding data of each chart. What are the best and easy way to do that?

Three options:

take a screenshot (yourself)
right-click the chart and "COPY", then paste to xls or whatever
write the data into an output file yourself (see help and example models, there are 1000s of ways of how to do this)

